# Wide to Long data frame returning NaN instead of float values

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape

I have a large data frame that looks like this:

```
     Country    2010         2011        2012         2013
0    Germany    4.625e+10    4.814e+10   4.625e+10    4.593e+10
1    France     6.178e+10    6.460e+10   6.003e+10    6.241e+10
2    Italy      4.625e+10    4.625e+10   4.625e+10    4.625e+10
```

I want to reshape the data so that the Country, Years, and Values are all columns. I used the melt method

```
dftotal = pd.melt(dftotal, id_vars='Country', 
              value_vars=[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2016,2017], 
              var_name ='Year', value_name='Total')
```

I was able to attain:

```
    Country    Year    Total
0   Germany    2010    NaN
1   France     2010    NaN
2   Italy      2010    NaN
```

My issue is that the float values turns into NaN and I don't how to reshape the data frame to keep the values as floats.

Comment: Maybe you should say how `Total` should be populated...

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `value_vars` argument and it works:

```
pd.melt(dftotal, id_vars='Country', var_name ='Year', value_name='Total')

    Country  Year         Total
0   Germany  2010  4.625000e+10
1    France  2010  6.178000e+10
2     Italy  2010  4.625000e+10
3   Germany  2011  4.814000e+10
4    France  2011  6.460000e+10
5     Italy  2011  4.625000e+10
6   Germany  2012  4.625000e+10
7    France  2012  6.003000e+10
8     Italy  2012  4.625000e+10
9   Germany  2013  4.593000e+10
10   France  2013  6.241000e+10
11    Italy  2013  4.625000e+10
```

The problem is probably that your column names are not `ints` but strings, so you *could* do:

```
dftotal = pd.melt(dftotal, id_vars='Country', 
              value_vars=['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2016','2017'], 
              var_name ='Year', value_name='Total')
```

And it would also work.

**Alternatively,** using `stack`:

```
dftotal = (dftotal.set_index('Country').stack()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={'level_1':'Year',0:'Total'})
          .sort_values('Year'))
```

Will get you the same output (but less succinctly)